# doctrine reference?

Tags: php, orm, documentation, doctrine

i've found one cheat sheet for doctrine: [cheat sheet](http://www.cheat-sheets.org/saved-copy/Doctrine-Cheat-Sheet-1.1.pdf)

but it doesn't list all methods for Doctrine_Record, Doctrine_Core, Doctrine_Query etc.

i wonder if there is a such reference?

Would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think so, 'cause such cheat sheets should contain only the most popular, useful methods and informations. But Doctrine's API is documented, so why don't you use official [Doctrine API Documentation](http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/api/1_2).

Comment: @AndrewAtkinson For Doctrine 1.2 see http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/ormold.html For Doctrine 2.x see http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm.html

Answer (score 0):

I find myself using the source itself as documentation when I need it. It's quite readable. Alternatively use something like http://www.phpdoc.org/ to make it more so.